# How is shared memory implemented in windows?

Tags: c++, windows, shared-memory

Where is the memory allocated? In which address space is the new memory?

Comment: None in particular, and all of them; the OS can map the same part of physical memory to each sharing process.

Comment: @david yes the one you mentioned

Comment: @david i want to know the general outline, not the nitty gritty implementation details.

Comment: @david sorry. I wanted to know about normal usage of shared memory.

Comment: Okay then. I fixed your question. You can delete your responses to me.

Comment: On a demand-paged virtual memory operating system like Windows, address space is allocated on disk.  Either in the paging file or a dedicated memory mapped file.  Every process can create a view on that storage, it doesn't have to be positioned at the same virtual memory address.  It gets fast by mapping the address space to RAM pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two common types of shared memory in Windows.

One is when more than one process maps the same file into memory. This obviously occurs with executables and libraries, but it can also occur with data files. Basically, the fact that processes are sharing this memory has almost no effect on how it works. It is implemented through the same demand paging as would occur if a single process had it mapped.

The other type is a shared, anonymous mapping. These can be created by calling the [CreateFileMapping](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366537%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function without specifying a valid file to map. This acts the same as if the memory was allocated, except that more than one process can access it. Just like normal memory usage, it can be paged to disk if it's not accessed or if RAM is needed for some other purpose.

For shared, anonymous mappings, the kernel gives processes a handle to the memory so that processes have a way to refer to it when they want to map it into their memory space.